# JMenuBar buttons not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jmenu, jmenubar

Trying to make a conversion calculator using JMenuBar and JMenu, however I can't seem to get the action listener to work as my GUI doesn't do anything when the user selects an option from the menu. I have a feeling its a problem with the Object source or my if statement but I'm really not sure as this is my first time using JMenus. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much!

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ConversionMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
   Object[] choice;
   double input;
   double peso1, yen1, euro1;
   String output;
   JLabel num = new JLabel("How much would you like to convert:   ");
   JTextField n1 = new JTextField(10);
   JLabel money = new JLabel();
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JLabel result = new JLabel("");
   JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
   JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
   JMenu menu = new JMenu("Convert");
   JMenu peso = new JMenu("To Mexican Peso");
   JMenu yen = new JMenu("To Japanese Yen");
   JMenu euro = new JMenu("To European Euro");
   JMenu close = new JMenu("Close");

  public ConversionMenu()
    {
       FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
       JPanel pane = new JPanel();
       pane.setLayout(flow);
       pane.add(num);
       pane.add(n1);
       pane.add(clear);
       pane.add(result);
       frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
       menubar.add(menu);
       menu.add(peso);
       peso.addActionListener(this);
       menu.add(yen);
       yen.addActionListener(this);
       menu.add(euro);
       euro.addActionListener(this);
       JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");
       menubar.add(exit);
       exit.add(close);
       close.addActionListener(this);
       setJMenuBar(menubar);
       setContentPane(pane);
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
     {      
      Object source = a.getSource();
      choice = menu.getSelectedObjects();
      input = Double.parseDouble(n1.getText());

       if(source == peso);
           {
           peso1 = input*19.08;
           output = String.format("$" + n1 + "American dollars is 
           equal to " + peso1 + "Mexican pesos.");
           result.setText(output);
            }
       if (source == yen)
           {
           yen1 = input*113.78;
           output = String.format("$" + n1 + "American dollars is equal 
           to " + yen1 + "Japanese yen.");
           result.setText(output);
           }
          else if (source == euro)
           {
            euro1 = input*0.86;
            output = String.format("$" + n1 + "American dollars is 
            equal to " + euro1 + "European euro.");
            result.setText(output);
            }
          else if (source == close)
           {
              System.exit(0);
           }
         if(source == clear)
          {
            n1.setText("");
            result.setText("");
           }

      }
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ConversionMenu con = new ConversionMenu();
    con.setTitle("Money Conversion Calculator");
    con.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    con.setSize(500, 500);
    con.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: JMenu's don't respond to ActionListeners. JMenuItems yes, but not JMenus.

Comment: A JMenuListener might work for you if you must respond to JMenu selection.

Comment: Thank you! i'll give that a shot!